# How to remove a exposed form on views result page

Tags: drupal, view, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created a exposed "form in block" on my views page which I am using on my front page. It redirects the user to the results page and displays the results and is working great.

However on the results page the form is still being displayed.
I want to get rid of this . Any idea how ?

I am using d7.

Cheers,
vishal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have this block set up in a region that is on your theme. The solution would be to do one of the following based on your preference:

1. If you only want the form to show on your homepage, edit the block (/admin/structure/block) and in your pages settings flag "Only on Listed pages" and type "" into the text area.
2. If you want the form to show on every page except your results page, edit the block and in your pages settings flag "All pages except those listed" and type the path of your search results view.

Comment: ur simple tip did it. here I was trying to override the template files